# Two different results in calling a function

Tags: javascript, methods, destructuring

The class in Udemy I'm going through had me create a function for ordering at a restaurant (to illustrate an example of Destructuring)

I noticed that I got two different results logged when I made a mistake of adding an extra set of brackets around returning a method inside of a function. I tried to explain to myself what the difference was that resulted in the difference but couldn't. It seems like it should be a basic explanation but I can't figure it out.

```js
const restaurant = {
  name: 'Classico Italiano',
  location: 'Via Angelo Tavanti 23, Firenze, Italy',
  categories: ['Italian', 'Pizzeria', 'Vegetarian', 'Organic'],
  starterMenu: ['Focaccia', 'Bruschetta', 'Garlic Bread', 'Caprese Salad'],
  mainMenu: ['Pizza', 'Pasta', 'Risotto'],

  order: function(starterIndex, mainIndex) {
    return [this.starterMenu[starterIndex], this.mainMenu[mainIndex]];
  }
}

console.log(restaurant.order(2, 0)); // ["Garlic Bread","Pizza"]
```

VS

```js
const restaurant = {
  name: 'Classico Italiano',
  location: 'Via Angelo Tavanti 23, Firenze, Italy',
  categories: ['Italian', 'Pizzeria', 'Vegetarian', 'Organic'],
  starterMenu: ['Focaccia', 'Bruschetta', 'Garlic Bread', 'Caprese Salad'],
  mainMenu: ['Pizza', 'Pasta', 'Risotto'],

  order: function(starterIndex, mainIndex) {
    return [this.starterMenu[starterIndex]], [this.mainMenu[mainIndex]];
  }
}

console.log(restaurant.order(2, 0)); // ["Pizza"]
```

Comment: Is it possible inline any relevant logs into the question as text, instead of screenshots on external websites?

Comment: How does restructuring come into the question? There doesn't appear to be any in the posted code. Also, please to not post code and results in linked images.

Comment: Are you able to clarify where you added the extra brackets in the second example to get a different result?

Comment: What you have in your second example is the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_operator), it first eveluates `[this.starterMenu[starterIndex]]`, so it creates an array with `'Garlic Bread'` bread in it, which isn't used, and then creates an array with `'Pizza'` in it, which is the last operand to be used in the comma operator `,` so that's what the comma operator ends up evaluating to and what you end up returning.

Comment: @traktor Sorry shouldn't have mentioned restructuring as there's none in the actual code. I was just in the Destructuring section in the class so thought I'd add that.

Comment: @NickParsons Ah I see! Didn't know about the 'comma operator'. I'll need to read up on it. Thank you v. much